How do we turn "Klein-Gordon space" into a Hilbert space?
This question is based on a footnote in Michael Talagrand's "What is a Quantum Field Theory?".
To understand the footnote, we need a few definitions: $X_m$ is the "mass shell," i.e., $$X_m = \{ \, (\omega, k) \in \mathbb R^{1,3} \, | \, \omega^2 = k^2 + m^2 \, \}.$$ $U$ is a specific representation of the Poincaré group acting on $L^2(X_m, \lambda_m),$ where $\lambda_m$ is the Poincaré-invariant measure on $X_m$. Namely, for $(a, A) \in \mathcal P$, we have $$U(a, A)(\varphi)(p)=e^{i\langle a, p\rangle} \varphi(A^{-1}p).$$
The footnote 42 on page 125 reads:

One can view (in a sense) $U(a,A)$ as operating on the space of functions on $\mathbb R^{1,3}$ whose Fourier transform is supported by $X_m$. These functions can be characterized by a certain differential equation, or “wave equation”, the Klein-Gordon equation which will play an important role later. This approach is very popular in physics. My problem here is that it is not clear what is the norm which makes the representation unitary. I never ran into a single textbook describing such a norm, or even mentioning the need for it, and I am unable to explain what is the mental picture physicists form at this point. More generally more complicated representations of the Poincaré group can be defined on more complicated spaces of functions satisfying certain wave equations.

So, what is the norm (in fact, inner product) that Talagrand wants but doesn't know? Actually, we need a little more than just an inner product: We need a rigorous definition of the space under consideration. Talagrand refers to "the space of functions on $\mathbb R^{1,3}$ whose Fourier transform is supported by $X_m$," but I think this needs more qualifications to make sense: Are we talking about Schwarz functions, or some other space of well-behaved functions? General $L^2$ functions are probably too broad, because $X_m$ is a set of measure zero in $\mathbb R^{1,3}$. Intuitively, the plane waves satisfying the KG equation correspond to delta functions on $X_m$, but we need to put this on rigorous footing and define an honest Hilbert space, and I'm not sure how this can be done.

Regarding your last paragraph: I think $L^2(X_m,\mathrm d\lambda)$ is well-defined. Is $X_m$ a set of measure zero with respect to the given measure?

@TobiasFünke I don't doubt that $L^2(X_m, d\lambda_m)$ is well defined. My doubt is about the "space of functions on $\mathbb R^{1,3}$ whose Fourier transform is supported by $X_m$."

Then I may misunderstand the question. Do you want to understand what Talagrand says about physicists?

@TobiasFünke No, I want the answer to the question Talagrand is asking (implicitly) in the sentence "my problem here is...". In other words, what is the norm on "that space," which makes the representation unitary? Note that "that space" is not $L^2(X_m, d\lambda_m)$, but rather some space $Y$ of functions satisfying the KG equation. To really answer Talagrand's question, you have to go further make precise what $Y$ even is. Moreover, I think $Y$ should be a Hilbert space and hence we really need an inner product on it, not just a norm.

In other words, I want to make Talagrand's (mathematical) idea precise and answer his (mathematical) question—not his question about physicists' mental picture.

@TobiasFünke Regarding your first question, $X_m$ has zero measure with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^{1,3}$, of which $X_m$ is a submanifold. Of course, $X_m$ has nonzero measure with respect to $d\lambda_m$.

Regarding your last comment: Yes, I agree, it is what I think but not explicitly checked (that was anyway not meant as a question, but more of a suggestion). But as it seems, I misunderstood your question. Regarding your actual question: It would be interesting to see what exactly Talagrand means here, i.e. what physicists write in certain QFT texts... but I don't know, it is not my field...

Good question. It exemplified a key issue I think that exists between what (particle) physicists typically do, and what mathematicians would consider well-defined. The issue comes about due to the fact that the system in question is infinite dimensional.
To illustrate the issue, let's generically say that $\hat{H}$ is a free-Hamiltonian with some associated equation of motion $Df=0$. (One can use the Klein-Gordon system as an example.) The eigenstates of the Hamiltonian $\phi$ are typically functions that cannot be normalized. However, being eigenstates of a Hermitian operator, they do obey some orthogonality condition. There is expected to be a very large degeneracy for such an infinite dimensional system. However, a suitable way to define orthogonal eigenstates within this degeneracy is to use plane wave eigenfunctions $\phi(\mathbf{k})$ which are parameterized by the wavevector $\mathbf{k}$. Now we can write the orthogonality condition as
$$ \langle\phi(\mathbf{k}_1),\phi(\mathbf{k}_2)\rangle = 2\pi\delta(\mathbf{k}_1-\mathbf{k}_2) . \tag{1} $$
Obviously these functions are not normalizable.
To resolve this issue, we can look at the solutions of the equation of motion instead of the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian. While all eigenfunctions are solutions of the equation of motion, the converse is not in general true. Therefore, there are many more solutions than eigenfunctions. One can select those solutions that can be normalized. The way to do that is to start with a space of well-defined normalizable functions $F(\mathbf{k})$ (for example Schwartz space), which we call spectra. While the plane waves also depend on the spacetime coordinates $\phi(\mathbf{x},t;\mathbf{k})$, these spectra only depend on the wavevector. So the space of solutions that we are looking for can now be defined by
$$ f(\mathbf{x},t) = \int F(\mathbf{k}) \phi(\mathbf{x},t;\mathbf{k}) d^3k . \tag{2} $$
This is somewhat related to an inverse Fourier transform, but the fact that we increase the number of dimensions need to be taking into account. It follows from the fact that the plane wave satisfy the equation of motion, which introduces a dimensional reduction. The space of solutions $f(\mathbf{x},t)$ inherits the properties of the space of spectra. The plane waves only serve to provide the orthogonality and completeness properties.
The space of solutions is an inner product space with an inner product inherited from the inner product between plane waves. For instance, consider an equal-time inner product between solutions:
$$ \begin{aligned}
\langle f_1, f_2 \rangle_t & = \int F_1^*(\mathbf{k}) 
\phi^*(\mathbf{x},t;\mathbf{k}) F_2(\mathbf{k}') \phi(\mathbf{x},t;\mathbf{k}') d^3k'  d^3k  d^3x \\
 & = \int F_1^*(\mathbf{k}) \delta(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}')
 F_2(\mathbf{k}') d^3k'  d^3k \\
 & = \int F_1^*(\mathbf{k}) F_2(\mathbf{k}) d^3k .
\end{aligned} \tag{3} $$
The properties of the spectra (Schwartz functions) allow us to change the order of integration. The resulting inner product is now simply defined as an integral over the spectra of the two solutions with one be complex conjugated. If we consider a complete space for the spectra (for example $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$ with Schwartz space being a dense subset), the completeness of the space of solutions thus follows from the properties of Fourier transforms, being an isometry between Hilbert spaces.

Response to comments: From the discussion in the comments it follows that the definition of the space of spectra is not a problem. Just to summarize, we can nominally take it as $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$. Eventually we'll want to restrict it to $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Note however, that at this point the idea of Lorentz invariance has no meaning. The relevant measure is just the standard Lebesgue measure.
The question now is how we define the "space of solutions." Nominally the solutions of the equation (or the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian) can be specified as the set of all plane waves $$\phi(\mathbf{x},t;\mathbf{k}) = \exp(-i\omega t + i \mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}) , $$
where
$$ \omega = c\sqrt{k_m^2+\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{k}} , $$
with $k_m$ being the wavenumber associated with the mass, is the dispersion relation (or mass-shell condition). As we already stated above, these plane waves obey an orthogonality condition given in (1). These plane waves also allow us to introduce the notion of Lorentz invariance.
Now we can define the solutions as in (2). (Let's represent the space of all such solutions by $\mathcal{F}$.) What does it mean? One may want to consider such solutions as elements of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^4,\mathbb{C})$, but not all functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^4,\mathbb{C})$ are solutions that can be expressed as (2). Therefore, the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}^4\equiv L^2(\mathbb{R}^4,\mathbb{C})$ does not represent $\mathcal{F}$. Nor can we say that $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{H}^4$, because the inner product is not the same. Instead the inner product is defined in (3) with the aid of (1). Therefore, $\mathcal{F}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{H}^3\equiv L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$, considered as the closure of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, with the isomorphism defined via (3).
So what is different about $\mathcal{F}$? The solutions in $\mathcal{F}$ allow us to introduce Lorentz transformations. Note however, that the definition of the inner product in (3) is not Lorentz invariant.
Did I manage to address all the issues now?

I feel that this answer provides a nice description of the physicist's intuition behind the space in question. However, I'm looking for a more precise mathematical description, at the level of Talagrand's footnote. In particular, what exactly are the "well-defined normalizable functions" you speak of? Must they be $C^2,$ or $C^\infty,$ or neither (in which case, we must define the differential operators in the KG equation more carefully)? What is the inner product that turns the space into a Hilbert space, and how do we know this inner product is complete?

Some detail is added. However, I don't want to go into too much detail, because there is some flexibility in how the detail can be specified.

I have a few questions about your updates. (1) Where does the frequency $\omega$ enter into your description? Should $\phi$ depend on $\omega$? (2) It appears that you have not just one inner product, but infinitely many, one for each $t$. Are you choosing a distinguished one for your Hilbert space? (3) The generic Schwarz space $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is not complete as an inner product space, hence not a Hilbert space. Are you claiming otherwise?

(1) The equation of motion (KG) leads to a dispersion relation that relates $\omega$ to $\mathbf{k}$. So everything that depends on $\mathbf{k}$ also depends on $\omega$ through $\mathbf{k}$. (2) Yes effectively we can specify different values for $t$ and obtain different inner products. This comes from the dimensional reduction that I mentioned. In effect one can fix the value of any of the coordinates to reduce the space from four-dimensional spacetime to a three dimensional space in defining the inner product. (3) I edited the last sentence to make a better more correct statement.

Ah, I think now I understand. You're saying $\mathcal H$ is the $L^2(\mathbb R^4)$-closure of space of $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^4)$ functions satisfying the KG equation?

Yes, as an example, but note that its should be $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ because of the dimensional reduction.

Hm, then I'm confused again. I think you're trying to say that the space of interest is isomorphic to $L^2(\mathbb R^3, d\lambda)$ for a certain measure $\lambda$ (i.e., square-integrable functions on the mass shell, c.f. Talagrand's original representation of $U$). But solutions to the KG equation are functions on $\mathbb R^4$—it makes no sense to take the $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$ closure of such solutions (not sure if that's what you were suggesting). I am interested in the "space of functions on $\mathbb R^{1,3}$" that Talagrand refers to.

So I'm afraid I still don't understand the Hilbert space you are describing. Does it consist of functions defined on $\mathbb R^3$ or $\mathbb R^4$? At this point, I think it would be helpful for me to see a concise and mathematically precise statement of the space you mean, something akin to "the $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$-closure of $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^4)$ functions satisfying the KG equation" that I tried a few comments back (but modified to describe the space you are intending).

Although the solutions of the KG equation are functions on $\mathbb{R}^4$, not every function on $\mathbb{R}^4$, is a solution. The subspace of valid solutions on $\mathbb{R}^4$ is isomorphic to functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$. That is why the spectra, which are functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$, are used to define the valid solutions on $\mathbb{R}^4$. The spectra on $\mathbb{R}^3$ don't need to solve any equations. Their mapping to functions on $\mathbb{R}^4$ via the plane waves ensure that those functions on $\mathbb{R}^4$ are valid solutions. Is it clearer now?

Thanks for the reward. I really want to make sure I clear up all your concerns. So, I'll make the necessary edits to the answer once I know how to explain it to your satisfaction.

I'm still unclear on the specifics, as much as I appreciate the answer and discussion. Let's call the two Hilbert spaces in question $\mathcal H^4$ and $\mathcal H^3$ (the former contains functions on $\mathbb R^4$, and the latter
on $\mathbb R^3$). I think I understand $\mathcal H^3$—it's just $L^2(\mathbb R^3, d\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lorentz-invariant measure. My question is, what is $\mathcal H^4$, and what is the isomorphism $\phi : \mathcal H^4 \to \mathcal H^3$ explicitly?

Please note that "subspace of valid solutions [to the KG equation]" is not mathematically precise. If we wish to interpret the differential operators literally, we should at least restrict to $C^\infty$. It is natural in this setting to restrict to $\mathcal S^4$, as we have discussed. But the resulting space is not a Hilbert space. I suggested taking the $L^2(\mathbb R^4)$ closure in order to cure this problem (a few comments back), but you seemed to resist this, instead referring back to $\mathcal H^3$. But I'm asking about $\mathcal H^4$, and this is where we seem to be stuck.

I would say the spectra are the values you integrate over and $F(k)$ is more akin to a spectral measure, but this was a fairly accurate representation of how mathematicians approach these problems. Griffiths even does this for plane wave solutions, so there's a nonrelativistic model to fall back on, too.

Thanks for adding the updates! I only just noticed them, and I haven't yet had much of a chance to look them over. I will read it carefully and try to respond within the next few days (the holiday is getting quite busy). Thank you for taking the time.
